# Did a review from review queue after limit, vote was counted, but doesn't show up in review's status now

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

After finishing my 20 posts for close reviewing, I noticed I had another tab with a post from the close review queue open. I voted to close, and got the usual "Thank you for reviewing..." message. Thinking my vote hadn't counted, I went back to the review post to go to the actual post page, where it said I had indeed VTC'd. But [the review page](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/665745) doesn't show my name. Shouldn't it, since it was the interface I used to VTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't and shouldn't count towards your review total. Doing so would allow users to load any number of reviews into as many tabs as their computer will handle and then sit there and review as many items as they want. You can complete any actions you would normally be able to complete and they will go through so long as you have enough votes left to do it, but it will not credit the review to you if you've already hit your review max, in the same way a vote to close will not get recorded if you've already hit your max.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean counting for the review total (I have long since exceeded any meaningful number on that count) - I meant that that post's review page should have shown me as having reviewed it.

Comment: @muru That's simply not possible without counting the review in your totals, nor is it something we should work around.

Comment: Oh, alright then - that said, would a "Leave Open" action have counted towards the three that kicks a post off the queue? I'm guessing it wouldn't, but just to be sure...

Comment: @muru No, it wouldn't.